# show $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n(a_n - n)$ exists

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $a_1 > 0$ and $a_{n+1} = a_n + \dfrac{n}{a_n}$. Show $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n(a_n - n)$ exists.

I think one can prove that either $n(a_n-n)$ or $a_n-n$ is monotone. Say $a_1 = 2.$ Then $a_2 = 2 + 1/2 = 5/2, a_3 = 5/2 + 2/(5/2) = 33/10,$ and the sequence $(a_n-n)$ seems to be decreasing. It is bounded below by zero so if we can prove the latter fact then it converges. Note that $a_{n}$ is a root of the quadratic equation $t^2 - a_{n+1} t +n = 0.$ So $a_n = \dfrac{a_{n+1} \pm \sqrt{a_{n+1}^2 - 4n}}{2}.$ To prove this, say $a_n - n < a_{n+1}-(n+1).$ Then $a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + \dfrac{n+1}{a_{n+1}}$ and so $a_{n+2}-(n+2) = a_{n+1}-(n+1) + \dfrac{n+1}{a_{n+1}} - 1 < a_{n+1}-(n+1),$ provided $a_{n+1} > n+1.$ But then one would need to add this to the inductive hypothesis and inductive step.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1493528/42969 or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2956144/42969